# File's last modified time not changing

Tags: c#, .net, system.io.file

I have written the following code in a Timer's Tick event to checking if the file modification time of an image has changed then copy that image and save it to another directory. Sometimes `GetLastWrittenTime()` doesn't change even though the file has already been overwritten.

```
 if (File.Exists(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\CaptureMerge.bmp"))
{   
     DateTime filetime=File.GetLastWriteTime(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\CaptureMerge.bmp");
     if (!filetime.Equals(lastmMdifiedTime))
     {
          if (txtkapan.Text != "" && txtlot.Text != "")
          {
              if (reg.Read("AUTOPATH") == null || reg.Read("AUTOPATH").Equals(""))
              {
                  Directory.CreateDirectory("D:\\" + txtkapan.Text + "\\" + txtlot.Text);
              }
              else
              {
                  Directory.CreateDirectory(reg.Read("AUTOPATH")+"\\" + txtkapan.Text + "\\" + txtlot.Text);
              }
              string image_name;
              if (txtlot.Text.Length <= 3 || txtparty.Text.Length <= 3 || txtkapan.Text.Length <= 3)
              {
                  image_name = txtparty.Text.Substring(0, txtparty.Text.Length) + "_" + txtkapan.Text.Substring(0, txtkapan.Text.Length) + "_" + txtlot.Text.Substring(0, txtlot.Text.Length) + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH_mm") + ".jpg";
              }
              else
              {
                  image_name = txtparty.Text.Substring(0, 3) + "_" + txtkapan.Text.Substring(0, 3) + "_" + txtlot.Text.Substring(0, 3) + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH_mm") + ".jpg";
              }
              try
              {
                  System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\CaptureMerge.bmp");
                  img.Save(reg.Read("AUTOPATH") + "\\" + txtkapan.Text + "\\" + txtlot.Text + "\\" + image_name, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                  lastmMdifiedTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\CaptureMerge.bmp");
              }
              catch (Exception ex)
              {
                  MessageBox.Show("Exception:" + ex.ToString());
              }
        }
        else  { }
  }
}
```

Please tell me what is wrong in my code.

Comment: How do you know it is not the same. You do not seem to make any log output. Did you step it through in debugger? Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: Could you reduce this problem to a [mcve] (emphasis on minimal)?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: If the code commented out does not actually help to reproduce the problem, please remove it.

Comment: Some more questions: What value does GetLastWriteTime return and have you tried also checking `GetCreationTime()` ?

Comment: I have checked by putting messagebox in last else part ut always goew in that else section